# Not able to select the disk during Oracle 11g Installation

Tags: oracle

[image]

Hi All, During the installation, I am not able to select the available disks which are already stamped using ASM. Any idea what could be the reason? I have tried to select using keyboard space as well but doesn't work out. Appreciate your help. Thanks.